# Accessing TextInput data in kivy without using ids

Tags: python, oop, kivy, grid-layout, textinput

here i've made a grid full of inputboxes using for-loop and added them to a dictionary to access later since i couldn't set id's in the python file. Now i'm trying to make a function that will make basic calculations based on the inputbox's data but i do not know how i can pass particular inputboxes in that function without using id's. Also the on_text function isn't working as i expected. I'm sure i'm missing something big here. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file("gridtable.kv")

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=6
        self.textinputs = {}
        for i in range(48):
            key = i+1
            self.textinputs[key] = TextInput(multiline=False,font_size=dp(30),on_text=self.calc(key))
            self.add_widget(self.textinputs[key])
        
    def calc(self,key):
        print(self.textinputs[key])

        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

```
<MyBox>:
    mygrid:my_grid
    orientation: "vertical"
    MyGrid:
        id: my_grid
        size_hint: 1,0.8
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1,0.2
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button: 
                text: "Expense Total:"
            Button: 
                text: "Revenue Total:"    
        Button:
            text: "Profit:"
            font_size: 40
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\jaika\OneDrive\Desktop\python\lil_curry_project\gridtable.py", line 38, in <module>
     MyApp().run()        

     print(self.textinputs[key])
 KeyError: 1
```

```
#better version of MyGrid()
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=4
        self.textinputs = [0]
        self.expense = 0
        self.revenue = 0
        self.profit = 0
        for i in range(16):
            t = TextInput(multiline=False,text=str(i+1))
            t.bind(on_text_validate=self.calc_profit)
            self.textinputs.append(t)
            self.add_widget(t)
        
    def calc_profit(self,instance):
        index = self.textinputs.index(instance)
        if index == 1 or index == 2 or index == 5 or index == 6 or index == 9 or index == 10 or index == 13 or index == 14:
            self.expense += int(instance.text)
        else:
            self.revenue += int(instance.text)
        self.profit = self.revenue - self.expense
        print(self.profit)
```

Comment: Do you need the dictionary for some other purpose or just to store the `TextInput` objects ?

Comment: The immediate error is that you are actually calling `self.calc(key)` in the line where you create the `TextInput`. Since that key is not yet in your `textinputs` dictionary, you get the `KeyError`.

Comment: @ApuCoder i made the dictionary to access particular inputboxes and pass them in the calc() method. Say i take the data from cell 1,1 and the data from cell 2,2, subtract the values n return profit. i initially wanted to set id's for every inputbox but i found out that you can't set id's in the python file.

Comment: @JohnAnderson well in the kv file the on_text property triggers the respective method only when something is typed in the textbox(not during creation since the textbox is empty) and i'm to do the exact same thing in the python file.

Comment: That is one place where `kv` and `python` differ. Add some prints in your `TextInput` creation loop to see what is happening.

Comment: okay i shall do that and try to understand this better. Could you please look at the comment i made on your code so i can go ahead an accept your answer.

Comment: @don'tdisplayname an event/property callback is enough to access the instance from which the event was fired/property was changed. Unless for some other usage, I think your query has already been answered.

Comment: @ApuCoder yes i have now understood how event callbacks works. thank you

Comment: @ApuCoder sorry to bother you again but i'm still struggling to access the instances as per their keys. i need the keys to know what to add and what to subtract. example value from cell(1,1) - value from cell (3,4)

Comment: @don'tdisplayname I can't follow you. Could you be more specific by updating your code (with some dummy instance/examples) ?

Comment: @ApuCoder okay i figured that what i need can be done with a list instead of a dict. I'm gonna try n add some sloppy block of code to the question to make myself clear

Comment: @ApuCoder i have added a better version of MyGrid() to make myself clear. it's sloppy rn but i'm gonna continue working on it. thank you

Comment: Still I can't follow your problem, it seems you're already doing what you expect. What different approach do you want?

Comment: @ApuCoder nothing really. i think i'm sorted for now. thank you

Comment: A quick note : you can use `if index in (1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14):` instead of creating multiple `or` statements in your modified code.

Comment: @ApuCoder yes i did think of that later. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind` to trigger a method call, or use events available in the `TextInput` (like `on_text_validate`). Here is a modified `MyGrid` class that uses both:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 6
        self.textinputs = {}
        for i in range(48):
            key = i + 1
            self.textinputs[key] = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=dp(30), on_text_validate=self.abba)
            self.textinputs[key].bind(text=partial(self.calc, key))
            print('in init, key =', key)
            self.add_widget(self.textinputs[key])

    def abba(self, ti_instance):
        print('abba, textinput instance =', ti_instance, ', text =', ti_instance.text)

    def calc(self, key, ti_instance, text):
        print('calc:')
        print('key =', key, ', text =', text, ', textinput instance =', ti_instance)
```

Note that the `bind` to `text` gets triggered with every change to the text in a `TextInput`. The `on_text_validate` will only be triggered when the user hits `Enter`.

Comment: okay the on_text_validate works perfectly like and thanks to you that i understand how the event actually works. Due to my ignorance i didn't really think that it would automatically pass that particular instance of the textinput as an argument.    the binding gives me an error though, it says "name partial is not defined". ```self.textinputs[key].bind(text=partial(self.calc, key))```

Comment: The binding is working now but i still couldn't figure out how to access the keys.

Comment: The key is passed as an argument to the `calc()` method.

Comment: okay. what's with the "partial" though?```self.textinputs[key].bind(text=partial(self.calc, key))``` do i need to define a new method called partial and pass the key in that? what am i missing here? could you please attach some link maybe that'll help me understand.

Comment: [**`partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial) is a higher-order function in python. Import it here as `from functools import partial`.